# Upgrade from MVC Web security Membership to Asp net Identity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I want to apply from MVC 4 to MVC 5 So i installed MVC 5 nugget package and changed all the references to new versions and now i am thinking of possibilities for migrating the membership feature to Asp net identity .

I have installed nuget package for ASP NET Identity

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core -Version 2.1.0
```

I am using EF 5 Do i need to Change this to EF 6 if i want to upgrade to ASP identity. 
How do i proceed further to replace Membership tables with new Asp identity tables and features.

Comment: I documented how I did it here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30578447/150342