# How to migrate from SimpleMembership to ASP.NET.Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, simplemembership

Migrating from MVC4 to MVC5 and want to use ASP.NET Identity too but I am struggling to find anything that covers everything I think I need to do to migrate the Identity. [Migrating an Existing Website from SimpleMembership to ASP.NET Identity](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/migrating-existing-website-from.html) suggests all I need to do is create an `ApplicationUser` and migrate the data, and other web searches give me sql scripts and passowrd hashing advice. But there are other loose ends that I'd like to clear up before I jump in.

First - I have code to initialise the membership system in my Seed method:

```
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(Config.ConnectionStringName,
        Config.UsersTableName,
        Config.UsersIDColumn,
        Config.UserNameColumn,
        autoCreateTables: true);
```

So that needs to go right?

Second - it looks like I need an `IdentityDbContext`. So should I change my existing context to inherit that?

i.e. instead of my current code `public class SID2013Context : DbContext` do this: `public class SID2013Context : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`

Will that generate a migration that creates the new tables I need to support ASP.NET Identity?

Once I've done that I should be able to pull in the `AccountController`, Views, ViewModels and start up code that is generated for an MVC5 project.

Can anyone answer the specific questions here and/or point me to a better resource?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity I hope it works for you, i love using identity,leave the old behind 

Comment: Note: this referenced article is a migration from Sql membership, which is the previous version before Simplemembership. Why they didn't provide a separate article I don't know :(

Comment: I put this in an answer but it was deleted - no idea why. Anyway this was helpful to me : https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Identity/SimpleMembershipSchemeUpdateMigration/readme.txt

Comment: And also this : http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2014/02/migrating-existing-website-from.html

Comment: @Simon_Weaver that is the link that I refer to in my question and in my answer. It tells you how to migrate to Identity tables, but still use `SimpleMembership`. I wanted to use `Identity` throughout

Comment: btw, http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2014/02/migrating-existing-website-from_16.html is an update of the post mentioned in this question (among other things, it mentions SimpleSecurity: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=simplesecurity )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I realised that the website I linked to in my question is telling you how to migrate to `Identity` tables, but still use `SimpleMembership`. I want to use Identity throughout, so I created an empty MVC application using Visual Studio so that I could copy in the code I wanted and fix it up. Here are the steps I followed to get Login and Logout working:

1. Added `ApplicationUser.cs` to my Models project
2. Added `IdentityConfig.cs` to my App_Start folder
3. Added `Startup.Auth.cs` to my App_Start folder
4. Added `AccountController.cs` to my Controllers folder (renamed existing controller)
5. Added `Startup.cs` to root folder
6. Added `AccountViewModels.cs` to ViewModels folder
7. Changed my context to inherit `IdentityDbContext` (it does indeed mean that new tables are created in a migration)
8. Added the required NuGet packages and fixed up all the namespaces
9. Project now builds
10. But `Add-Migration` gave an error ... "EntityType IdentityUserRole has no key defined"
11. ....solved that by adding a call to `base.OnModelCreating` in my override
12. `Add-Migration` & `Update-Database` - adds the tables required
13. Added my custom fields in `UserProfile` to `ApplicationUser` and updated the database
14. Used sql (in a migration) to copy data from old tables to new tables. Sql included here. NB need to populate `SecurityStamp` with a Guid to prevent error during Login
15. That's got Login and Logout working
16. Removed `UserProfile`, `SimpleRoleProvider` and `RoleManager` classes - replacing the code where necessary.
17. Removed references to `WebMatrix.Data` and `WebMatrix.WebData` dlls
18. Removed `<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="simple">` and `<membership defaultProvider="simple">` from web.config

Sql used in step 14:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.aspnetusers (id
, email
, emailconfirmed
, passwordhash
, securitystamp
, phonenumber
, phonenumberconfirmed
, twofactorenabled
, lockoutenddateutc
, lockoutenabled
, accessfailedcount
, username
, organisationid
, firstname
, lastname
, inactive)
    SELECT
        u.id,
        u.username Email,
        m.isconfirmed EmailConfirmed,
        m.password PasswordHash,
        --SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync (used in Login method) 
        --throws an exception http://stackoverflow.com/a/23354148/150342
        NEWID() SecurityStamp, 
        u.telephone PhoneNumber,
        CASE
            WHEN u.telephone IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END PhoneNumberConfirmed,
        0 TwoFactorEnabled,
        NULL LockoutEndDateUtc,
        0 LockoutEnabled,
        m.passwordfailuressincelastsuccess AccessFailedCount,
        u.username,
        u.organisationid,
        u.firstname,
        u.lastname,
        u.inactive
    FROM dbo.userprofiles u
        INNER JOIN dbo.webpages_membership m
            ON m.userid = u.id
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT
        1
    FROM dbo.aspnetusers
    WHERE id = u.id)

INSERT INTO dbo.aspnetroles (id
, name)
    SELECT
        roleid,
        rolename
    FROM dbo.webpages_roles r
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT
        1
    FROM dbo.aspnetroles
    WHERE roleid = r.roleid)

 INSERT INTO dbo.aspnetuserroles (userid
    , roleid)
        SELECT
            userid,
            roleid
        FROM dbo.webpages_usersinroles ur
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT
            1
        FROM dbo.aspnetuserroles
        WHERE userid = ur.userid
        AND roleid = ur.roleid)
```