# Is it possible to upgrade an existing MVC4 Web application to MVC5?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

The reason why I want to upgrade from MVC4 to MVC5 is because MVC5 has Entity Framework Identity already there. I don't want to spend time trying to add Identity to my MVC4 project because it'll take too much time.

Is there like an update button which does it automatically or do I need to create a MVC5 template and copy codes over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded form MVC4 to MVC5 by following the steps at this link

[How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

that walk you through steps to upgrade from MVC4 to MVC5

Here is a quick summary of the upgrade steps.

1. > Backup your project, as it upgrade will involve changes to package configuration and web.config files.
2. > upgrade from Web API to Web API 2 by making some changes in `global.asax`
3. > Make sure all the packages that your projects use are compatible with  MVC 5 and Web API 2. They provide a table of package versions from Microsoft packages
4. > Open project in Visual Studio.
5. > Using Package Manager Console (PMC), remove certain ASP.Net NuGet packages if installed.
6. > Upgrade all the ASP.Net NuGet packages using the PMC

They show how to: Update the `Application web.config File` and `Update the web.config files under the Views folder`

Check out the link and see if that helps.

Comment: Is it possible to just create a new MVC5 project. Import Models,Viewmodels,Controllers and Views over? It seems like such a hassle to do all those things.

Comment: Yes you could. But it's good to know if any of what you are bringing over will have any issues on the other version. I wend the upgrade route as I wasn't sure what would break if I created a new project

Comment: Ok. I didn't realize that because I had forked the PageList.MVC code locally into my project and haven't had any issues with it since the upgrade.

Comment: It was my mistake! It's actually there.

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded from MVC4 to MVC5 by copying some files from the existing MVC4 project and some files from a new MVC5 web application project into a new empty project.

The issue for me was migrating from `SimpleMembership` authentication to Identity. I documented the steps I took in this answer: [How to migrate from SimpleMembership to ASP.NET.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30578447/150342)

If you aren't using `SimpleMembership` already, I would copy files straight from the MVC4 to the MVC5 Web Application.

Comment: What if I am using Simple Membership but I want to use Identity because of Email Verification or reset password etc?

Comment: I think that `SimpleMembership` and `Identity` are mutually exclusive