# Migrating an MVC4 application to an MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application that is done by using MVC4.

I want to update it to an MVC5 for using API controller for making back-end services...

What is the best way to do to **Migrate an MVC4 application to an MVC5**?

Comment: If I recall correctly, MVC5 was more-or-less a drop-in replacement for MVC4. Just update your nuget package versions.

Comment: Thank you @vcsjones

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to upgrade an existing MVC4 Web application to MVC5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172440/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-an-existing-mvc4-web-application-to-mvc5)

Comment: @vcsjones, need manual edits too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2